# Запуск функции после того как закончатся две другие

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, асинхронность

Есть две функции, первая анимация и вторая асинхронная ajax загрузка данных для замены контента.

как запустить функцию по завершению загрузки и анимации?

все через jquery.

Запуск

- click по ссылке
- начало ajax загрузки контента в переменную
- Начало анимации

фактически, идея плавной анимацией элемента скрыть загрузку, вместо показала preload'еров.

Comment: Анимация на чем? И в какой момент времени запускается?

Comment: Если только вторая асинхронная, то вызов функции включите в колбек промиса загрузки данных.

Comment: Анимация через jquery, допустим fadeOut или fadeIn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам нужно завести переменную счетчик и в каждой асинхронной процедуре увеличивать ее на 1. Как только она достигнет значения 2 - все процедуры выполнены

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  $('button').click(function() {
    var status = 0;
    function incStatus() {
      status++;
      if (status === 2)
        console.log('End process');
    }
    $('.anim').fadeToggle(500, function() {
      console.log('End animation');
      incStatus();
    });
    setTimeout(function() {
      console.log('End ajax');
      incStatus();
    }, 300);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Click</button>
<div class="anim">Animation</div>
```

Comment: Отлично, искал различные обработки, а до вызываемой функции счетчика и не додумался вовсе.
Спасибо